# how to apply effect on image in android like distort, spotlight,exposure and many more

Tags: android, image, effect

i don't know how to apply math calculation on image. so is there any ready made library and tutorial available to apply effect on image?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

or this http://developers.aviary.com/mobile-api

Answer (score 4):

Refer to http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html it mentions most of the image processing techniques with code and proper description

[image: Guassian blur]